# NSIS: How to get a finish- and a next-button?

Tags: installation, nsis, nsis-mui

I use the `MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES`. And this page has normally a finish-button, but I have a custom page after it. But I want that you could still finish the installer before the custom page and the next page is only optional. I could also show more code if wished.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE $(license)
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page custom TestSettings
```

At the moment I have a previous-, next- and cancel-button at the instfile page. But I want a prev-, next- and finish-button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS was never designed to support this but with the [ButtonEvent plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/ButtonEvent_plug-in) you can make it work. I'm just not sure if it makes sense because if the last page is important then some users might skip the page by accident because they are not paying attention.

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE $(license)
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE InstFilesLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page custom TestSettings
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!include WinMessages.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Function InstFilesLeave
GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent 2
ShowWindow $0 0
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(pr0,@r1)' ; NSIS 3+
System::Call 'USER32::MapWindowPoints(p0,p $hWndParent, p $1, i 2)'
System::Call '*$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)'
IntOp $4 $4 - $2
IntOp $5 $5 - $3
!define IDC_MYFINISHBTN 1337
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i 0, t "BUTTON", t "&Finish", i ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${WS_TABSTOP}, ir2, ir3, i r4, i r5, p $hWndParent, p ${IDC_MYFINISHBTN}, p 0, p 0)p.r1'
SendMessage $0 ${WM_GETFONT} "" "" $0
SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1
GetFunctionAddress $0 OnFinishButton
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_MYFINISHBTN} $0
FunctionEnd

Var JustFinish

Function OnFinishButton
StrCpy $JustFinish 1
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_COMMAND} 1 ""
FunctionEnd

Function TestSettings
StrCmp $JustFinish "" +2
    Return
GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent ${IDC_MYFINISHBTN}
ShowWindow $0 0
GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent 2
ShowWindow $0 1
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Configure" "Blah blah blah"
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
; ...
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

If your custom page just contains a couple of checkboxes then you can [use the MUI Finish page with custom texts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065825#https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517851) instead.